# How are CouchDB 2.0 nodes split across servers?

Tags: sharding, couchdb-2.0

Looking at one of the CouchDB 2.0 lead-up blog posts ([here](https://blog.couchdb.org/2016/08/01/couchdb-2-0-architecture/)), there is mention of shards (`q`), copies (`n`) and nodes.

Reading up on Couch 2.0 suggests (to me at least) that a node is basically an instance of Couch, which can either be a shard or a shard-copy. Is that correct? i.e. if you have 8 shards (`q=8`) and 3 copies of each shard (`n=3`), then you have 24 nodes?

How should these nodes be split across servers and will it do this automatically? If you have 8 shards should you have a cluster of 8 servers?

Comment: Looking at CouchDB docs, I realize this question is answered in a very clear way in chapter 11 (Cluster Reference): http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/cluster/

Comment: The information is easily available elsewhere